# EdgeLabels and EdgeLabelStyle of Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, neural-networks

I try to name edges according to the nodes emerging from them and entering them. Each edge takes a specific name $e_{ij}$.

The following example illustrates what is required

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
 VertexStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 12], VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]

I would like the edges to be named as in the figure below:

[image]

If it is possible to develop the above figure to be as in the figure below:

[image]

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Black, 
 VertexStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> 
   Placed[Framed[Style[Subscript["e", Row[List @@ e]], 16, Italic, Bold, White],
     Background -> Black, FrameStyle -> Black], "Middle"]}, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 12], 
 VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]